# Cannot print on GeoExplorer (Communication Trouble: Status undefined)

Tags: geoserver, printing, pdf, geoexplorer, config.yaml

### **Software setup and information**

I'm using GeoExplorer to access layers served by GeoServer (on my localhost) which in turn is linked to a PostGIS database (local again). I'm using GeoServer 2.5, so I downloaded the v2.5 print plugin and followed the instructions [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html).

### **Issue**

When I click the print button, the print preview pops up and I can edit my printing options as expected. However when I try to Print, the software tries to "Export to PDF" but fails, producing an error box which states: "Communication Trouble: Status undefined"

### **Steps taken to resolve issue**

I've attempted to play with the config.yaml file located in the GeoServer directory according to the MapFish documentation (http://www.mapfish.org/doc/print/configuration.html) but being new to all this, I haven't been able to make it work... At the minute I'm using the standard config.yaml file generated when I restarted GeoServer after installing the print plugin (pasted below)

### **config.yaml:**

```
#===========================================================================
# allowed DPIs
#===========================================================================
dpis: [75, 150, 300]

#===========================================================================
# the allowed scales
#===========================================================================
scales:
  - 25000
  - 50000
  - 100000
  - 200000
  - 500000
  - 1000000
  - 2000000
  - 4000000

#===========================================================================
# the list of allowed hosts
#===========================================================================
hosts:
  - !localMatch
    dummy: true
  - !ipMatch
    ip: www.camptocamp.org
  - !dnsMatch
    host: demo.opengeo.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: terraservice.net
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: sigma.openplans.org
  - !dnsMatch
    host: demo.mapfish.org

layouts:
  Legal:
    mainPage:
      pageSize: LEGAL
      items:
        - !map
          spacingAfter: 30
          width: 440
          height: 483
  #===========================================================================
  A4 portrait:
  #===========================================================================
    metaData:
#      title: '${mapTitle}'
      author: 'MapFish print module'
      subject: 'Simple layout'
      keywords: 'map,print'
      creator: 'MapFish'

    titlePage:
      pageSize: A4
      items:
        - !text
          spacingAfter: 150
        - !text
          font: Helvetica
          fontSize: 40
          spacingAfter: 100
          align: center
          text: '${layout}'
        - !image
          maxWidth: 160
          maxHeight: 160
          spacingAfter: 100
          align: center
          url: http://trac.mapfish.org/trac/mapfish/attachment/ticket/3/logo_v8_sphere.svg?format=raw

      footer: &commonFooter
        height: 30
        items:
          - !columns
            config:
              cells:
                - paddingBottom: 5   
            items:
              - !text
                backgroundColor: #FF0000
                align: left
            text: a red box
              - !text
                align: right
                text: 'Page ${pageNum}'
              - !image
                align: center
                maxWidth: 100
                maxHeight: 30
                spacingAfter: 200
                url: 'http://geoserver.org/download/attachments/10158143/pbGS-Bttn228x68.png'

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mainPage:
      pageSize: A4
      rotation: true
#      header:
#        height: 50
#        items:
#          - !text
#            font: Helvetica
#            fontSize: 30
#            align: right
#            text: '${layout}'
      items:
        - !text
          text: '${mapTitle}'
          fontSize: 30
          spacingAfter: 30
        - !map
          spacingAfter: 30
          width: 440
          height: 483
        - !columns
          # columns can have an absolute position. In that case, they need the 3 following fields:
          absoluteX: 410
          absoluteY: 310
          width: 100
          items:
            - !scalebar
              type: bar
              maxSize: 100
              barBgColor: white
              fontSize: 8
              align: right
        - !text
          text: '${comment}'
          spacingAfter: 30
        - !attributes
          source: data
          spacingAfter: 30
          columnDefs:
            id:
              columnWeight: 2
              header: !text
                text: ID
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !text
                text: '${id}'
            name:
              columnWeight: 5
              header: !text
                text: Name
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !columns
                config:
                  cells:
                    - backgroundColor: '${nameBackgroundColor}'
                      borderWidth: 1
                      borderColor: '${nameBorderColor}'
                items:
                  - !text
                    text: '${name}'
            icon:
              columnWeight: 2
              header: !text
                text: Symbol
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !image
                align: center
                maxWidth: 15
                maxHeight: 15
                url: 'http://www.mapfish.org/svn/mapfish/trunk/MapFish/client/mfbase/mapfish/img/${icon}.png'
        - !text
          font: Helvetica
          fontSize: 9
          align: right
          text: '1:${scale} ${now MM.dd.yyyy}'
      footer: *commonFooter
```

Anyone have ideas how I can get my maps to export to pdf from GeoExplorer?

Answer (score 1):

This configuration in my case, work well:

```
dpis: [75, 150, 300]

scales:
    - 524288000
    - 262144000
    - 131072000
    - 65536000
    - 32768000
    - 16384000
    - 8192000
    - 4096000
    - 2048000
    - 1024000
    - 512000
    - 256000
    - 128000
    - 64000
    - 32000
    - 16000
    - 8000
    - 4000
    - 2000
    - 1000

hosts:
    - !localMatch
         dummy: true
     - !ipMatch
         ip: 0.0.0.0
         mask: 0.0.0.0

layouts:

    A4:
    metaData: &commonMetaData
        title: "${mapTitle}"
        author: "xxxx"
        subject: "yyyyy"
        keywords: "map,print"
        creator: "OpenGeo Suite"
        mainPage:
        pageSize: A4
        rotation: true
        items:
            - !text
                text: "${mapTitle}"
                fontSize: 30
                spacingAfter: 30
                align: center
            - !map
                spacingAfter: 10
                width: 440
                height: 600
            - !scalebar
                type: bar
                maxSize: 100
                barBgColor: white
                fontSize: 8
                align: right
                spacingAfter: 10
            - !text
                text: "${comment}"

Legal:
    metaData: *commonMetaData
    mainPage:
        pageSize: LEGAL
        rotation: true
        items:
            - !text
                text: "${mapTitle}"
                fontSize: 30
                spacingAfter: 30
                align: center
            - !map
        spacingAfter: 10
                width: 440
                height: 650
            - !scalebar
                type: bar
                maxSize: 100
                barBgColor: white
                fontSize: 8
                align: right
                spacingAfter: 10
            - !text
                text: "${comment}"

Letter:
    metaData: *commonMetaData
    mainPage:
        pageSize: LETTER
        rotation: true
        items:
            - !text
                text: "${mapTitle}"
                fontSize: 30
                spacingAfter: 30
                align: center
            - !map
                spacingAfter: 10
                width: 440
                height: 550
            - !scalebar
                type: bar
                maxSize: 100
                barBgColor: white
                fontSize: 8
                align: right
                spacingAfter: 10
            - !text
                text: "${comment}"
```